# Use required attribute in knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.2

How can I conditionally set a `required` attribute in an input ?

```
<input type="text" required />
```

The required attribute has not value. Just by being present will be taken as `required`. So `required="false"` will make some scripts fail.

I was not able to find anything like it in the docs. The closer I got was the `disabled` binding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Knockout is smart enough to remove attributes whose bound value is `false` when they are bound with the `attr` [binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html). Inspect the input below. It will switch between `required="true"` and `required` not appearing.

```js
vm = {r: ko.observable(false)}
ko.applyBindings(vm);
setInterval(() => vm.r(!vm.r()), 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input data-bind="attr: {required: r}" />
```